# join two objects that have the same key into a collection php laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I am working with collections in Laravel and I have the following problem, I need to join objects that have the same key inside the array, at the same time obtain the total sum of one of its keys, this is a summary of my collection:

```
[
  {
    "cta_debe": 20,
    "total": "2000.00",
  },
  {
    "cta_debe": 22,
    "total": "3600.00",
  },
  {
    "cta_debe": 22,
    "total": "1000.00",
  },
  {
    "cta_haber": 10,
    "total": "5000.00",
  },
  {
    "cta_haber": 10,
    "total": "4000.00",
  }
]
```

where I have several objects that have the keys "cta_debe" and "cta_haber" with the same value, then I would like to join all the equal objects into one, in addition to adding the total column, this is an example of how I expect the collection to be :

```
[
  {
    "cta_debe": 20,
    "total": "2000.00",
  },
  {
    "cta_debe": 22,
    "total": "4600.00",
  },
  {
    "cta_haber": 10,
    "total": "9000.00",
  },
]
```

any idea how i could do this?

Comment: will the `cta_*` keys always start with `cta_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preparing data as yours.

```
$data = collect([
    collect(['cta_debe' => 20, 'total' => '2000.00']),
    collect(['cta_debe' => 22, 'total' => '3600.00']),
    collect(['cta_debe' => 22, 'total' => '1000.00']),
    collect(['cta_haber' => 10, 'total' => '5000.00']),
    collect(['cta_haber' => 10, 'total' => '4000.00']),
]);
```

Your solution start from here..

```
$collection = $data->groupBy(

        fn ($item, $key) => $item->keys()->first()

    )
    ->flatMap(function($groupValue, $groupKey){

        return $groupValue->groupBy($groupKey)

            ->map(function($value, $key) use ($groupKey) {

                return collect([

                    $groupKey => $key,

                    'total' => $value->map(

                        fn ($item) => (float) $item['total']

                    )->sum()
                ]);

            });

    })
    // ->all(); // if you need array as output
    ->collect();
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: the problem is that this should also work for any other key as I mentioned in my question for "cta_haber" and not only for "cta_debe"

Comment: @JSTECH why are you not using the collections method for the loops? You should probably replace the `foreach` with the [`each` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-each)

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection methods:

```
$result = collect($myArray)->groupBy(function ($item) {
   $keys = Arr::only($item, [ 'cta_debe', 'cta_haber' ]);
   return count($keys) > 0 ? array_keys($keys)[0].'-'.$keys[0] : '';
})->filter(fn ($item, $key) => $key !== '')
  ->map(function ($group, $id) {
   [ $key, $value ] = explode('-', $id);
   return [
       $key => $value,
       'total' => collect($group)->sum('total')
   ];
});
```

What this does is: it groups by either `cta_debe` or `cta_haber` and creates groups that will be keyed by e.g. `cta_debe-20` etc (this is in case there's items with the same identifier but different key). It then sums everything within the total of that group and returns that with the group name and identifier.

Comment: the problem is that this should also work for any other key as I mentioned in my question for "cta_haber" and not only for "cta_debe"

Comment: I've updated that

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would probably do it.

Note: *this solution assumes that the `cta_*` key is always the first key in the sub arrays.*

Convert the whole array to collections and then use collection methods and Laravel helpers to get to the desired result.

```
$groupedData = 
  $arr
    ->groupBy(fn ($item, $key) => $item->keys()->first())
    ->flatMap(
      fn($groupValue, $groupKey) => 
        $groupValue
          ->groupBy($groupKey)
          ->map(
            fn($value, $key) => [
                $groupKey => $key,
                'total' => $value->map(
                    fn ($item) => (float) $item['total']
                )->sum()
              ]
            )
    );
dump($groupedData->all());
```

[Collections docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections)
[Helpers Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers)

Laravel methods used:

[flatMap()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-flatmap)

[groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby)

[map()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-map)

[keys()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-keys)

[first()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-first)

[sum()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sum)

This solution is based on @JSTECH 's solution, but it is converted to use Laravel collections and method chaining